# Mathematical function for Decimal Digits

Tags: apex, math

Is there a way to get exact value for division operation like 1/24 to get exact value as

```
1/24 = 0.04166666666
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a decimal. You can use the `divide` method if you want to specify a number of digits.

```
system.assertEquals(0, 1/24);
system.assertEquals(0.0416666666666666666666666666666667, 1.0/24);
system.assertEquals(0.04167, 1.0.divide(24, 5));
```

Comment: Devide method seems better option.